# While he lay the worst, he would have me constantly by his pillow

Tags: meaning

I am now reading [*Wuthering Heights*](https://www.ucm.es/data/cont/docs/119-2014-04-09-Wuthering%20Heights.pdf), and this sentence is from that novel:

> Heathcliff was dangerously sick; and while he **lay at the worst he
>   would have me constantly by his pillow**: I suppose he felt I did a
>   good deal for him, and he hadn’t wit to guess that I was compelled to
>   do it.

What does it mean? It can't use the verb *lay* meaning to put down, with *the worst* being the direct object, because that makes no sense in context. It clearly has to be the past tense of *to lie*, meaning to recline in bed (if only because of the *pillow*), but how can reclining have a comparative sense?

Answer (score 2):

While he was in the worst stage of his illness, he wanted me to be constantly at his bedside.

Comment: Some of you are over-engineering that, as I hope can be seen between TonyK’s transliteration and the original: in the worst stage of his illness, he lay in bed…

Answer (score 1):

*To lie* (past form, *lay*) means to be in or take a recumbent position, which we use in ordinary conversation when we say "I lay down to take a nap." But the word has an additional meaning, one that predates that ordinary one, a meaning that the *OED* can trace to 893:

> To be or remain in a specified position of subjection, helplessness,
>   misery, degradation, or captivity<sup>*</sup>

This connotation is preserved in the idiom *lay open*, in which the meaning of *open* is vulnerable or defenseless. For example from [*Archaeologia Graeca Or the Antiquities of Greece, Volume 2*](https://books.google.com/books?id=mlUPAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA89&dq=%22lay%20open%20to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwji2fay4OLOAhXHJiYKHYs1D8o4WhDoAQhFMAc#v=onepage&q=%22lay%20open%20to%22&f=false) by John Potter

> their Cities were not fortify'd with Walls, but **lay open** to all the Invaders

Back to Heathcliff. The passage describes Heathcliff on his sickbed at the direst point in the course of his illness.

---

* In a now-archaic usage, the word meant to languish in prison.